# Unable to show images from local file and giving error

Tags: javascript, html, filereader, fileapi

I would like to know that how can I show the images from uploaded file from the local system, as I can able to upload but failing it on showing the image from the uploaded file as I'm getting the **following error**:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/Users/Desktop/Image1.nii Cross
>   origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data,
>   chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
>
> Uncaught Error: Loading failed
>   Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load
>   'file:///D:/Users/Desktop/Image1.nii'.

But I can drag and drop or upload the files like above at: http://slicedrop.com/.

Comment: File has to be under same domain!

Comment: Why would it load, its a browser app it can't just load from a local path, give a relative path, make an images folder and use the relative path

Comment: @RayonDabre : haha! If the file has to be under same domain, would users really need to upload the file to the server then? What you should say here that the API to upload file has to be in the same domain as that of the API calling domain :)

Comment: Due to security reasons browsers doesn't have access to your file system. You can use activx object(for ie) or disable browser security like "chrome.exe --disable-web-security".

Comment: @AdityaParab, As mentioned in the question, images are already uploaded on the server and he is trying to display images from the local machine. This is what I got from the question. Correct me if I am wrong!

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of **CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing)** at work. To disable it, you can supply these flags to Chrome before starting it -
On Windows - `chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files`
On OSX - `open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ --args --allow-file-access-from-files`